# How do I end the game loop to change Scenes after a time limit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a simple game in Sprite Kit which waits until a certain time limit to switch scenes for the next level.  At the end of the time limit, if the user has not already died and hit a game-over scenario, the game switches scenes to a 'next level' scene and then proceeds to the next level.  The Game Over scene works okay when my character dies, but the time limit check seems to be the issue.

Currently in my game I hit my time limit by using a `totalTimePlayed` property in my `update` method.  At this point the game will crash and not allow any more input.  I'm doing this check and calling a method from my update method, so I don't know why it's trying to keep updating before I switch scenes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some playing around I was able to answer my problem on my own.

My solution was to add a `switchingScenes BOOL` property to my implementation that is initialized to `NO` by default.  I hit my `totalTimePlayed` limit in my `update` method and set `isNextLevel` to `YES`.  The next time through the update loop this code gets executed:

```
if (self.isNextLevel) {
        // if you're already in the process of switching scenes, wait
        if (!self.switchingScenes) {
            self.switchingScenes = YES;
            LevelSwitchScene *levelSwitch = [LevelSwitchScene sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];
            levelSwitch.nextLevel = @"level2";
            SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:0.5];
            [self.view presentScene:levelSwitch transition:transition];
        }
    }
```

So the problem was my scene switching just kept attempted to update over and over again faster than the scene switch could happen, causing it to freeze.  By adding the `switchingScenes` keyword I was able to make sure this code block is only called once, averting the crash.  The actual scene change happens at 10.511981 seconds, so there's a noticeable delay to switch scenes that you have to account for.

Hopefully my own answer has been clear.  If there is a better way to accomplish this, please add your own solution.